# Rails mailer and links not working under Thunderbird

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, thunderbird

I want to send html email's with my Rails Mailer.
Could be `multipart/alternative` or only `text/html`.
Problem is, when I send an email with a link, it appears well on Gmail, but not so good in Thunderbird.

The problem is, that in Thunderbird, the link is 'not clickable' - it's highlighted like a link, but clicking on it does nothing.

Links on other mails (not sent from Rails Mailer) work flawlessly.

So my question is: how to properly send an html email, so it will be viewed properly?

**Mailer code:**

```rb
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def mailing_delivery(email, subject)
    mail(:to => email, :subject => subject)
  end
```

**Mail view:**

```
# mailing_delivery.html.haml 
%p
  Thanks! Its your mailer!
%p
  = link_to "Google", "google.com"
```

**Source of email** *(some parts cut-out)*:

```
Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2011 14:32:34 +0200
From: xxx
To: xxx
Message-ID: <4e4d0662bf96e_41024be957a57974@xxx.mail>
Subject: Super news!
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-O2-Trust: 2, 64
X-O2-SPF: neutral

<p>
  Thanks! It's your mailer!
</p>
<p>
  <a href="google.com">Google</a>
</p>
```

Of course Rails 3. Thunderbird 5.0, but that's not the issue - because somehow other mails show up good.. And I don't think it's app specific.

What should I do, to make this work?

**Edit:** I tried to change the 'content-transfer-encoding' header with no success, by doing `mail(:to => email, :subject => subject, "Content-Transfer-Encoding" => value)` or in class `default "Content-Transfer-Encoding" => value` with no luck.. how to change that?

Emails that works good under Thunderbird have `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` (or eventually `base64`) so maybe that's the issue? How do I change it?

**Edit 2:** I managed to change the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` to `quoted-printable` but it's cutting the content, like this:

```
Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2011 22:04:21 +0200
From: xxx
To: xxx
Message-ID: <4e4d704557839_151c4e4957c2132e@xxx.mail>
Subject: Super news!
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-O2-Trust: 2, 63
X-O2-SPF: neutral

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://ww=
w.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      Thanks! It's your mailer!
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href=
```

One other thing: why is there a newline in `Content-Type` ? I didn't see it in other (working good) mails. How I can get rid of it?

Comment: are you sending both a text/plain and an html part, or just the html part

Comment: both ways is the same. even on `multipart/alternative` - `text/plain` goes well, but `text/html` with encoding `quoted-printable` is cutting the content..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it'll work if you fix your html. So instead of just having:

```
<p>
  Thanks! It's your mailer!
</p>
<p>
  <a href="google.com">Google</a>
</p>
```

try:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      Thanks! It's your mailer!
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @schiza - OK, how about fixing your link? Try `<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>` instead of `<a href="google.com">Google</a>`.

Comment: omg... yeah, that helped. I didn't thought about it.. I'm surprised that Thunderbird can manage link like 'google.com' in plain text (and make it a link) but can't manage `a href` link without protocol... I tried so many things, and that I omitted. thank you :)