# Why is Link in Rails Mailer Email Showing Incorrectly?

Tags: actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6

'Rails 6.1', 'ruby 3.1.1'

This is the first time I've added a link in an html email sent via a rails mailer.  The email works, it's sent (to me) and I can see it.  But the hyperlink in it is showing oddly. Instead of showing as a clickable link, it shows with brackets `[ ]`, which are not in the link_to tag text or path. In the line below, `Living Muay Thai Students Site` should be the clickable text in the link. Not sure why it's showing like this.

`[www.johndcowan.com/living_muay_thai]Living Muay Thai Student Site`

Code:

```
# mailer

def new_student_badge_email
  @student = params[:student]
  @badge = params[:badge]
  @admin = params[:admin]
  @url = 'www.johndcowan.com/living_muay_thai'
    
  mail(to: @student.email, subject: 'LMT: You Earned a New Badge')
end


# html email (in part)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Dear <%= @student.full_name %>
...
...
      You can login to the <%= link_to("Living Muay Thai Student Site", @url) %> and view all your badges.
...
```

When I get the email, the `link_to` link gets changed to this (as noted above):

```
[www.johndcowan.com/living_muay_thai]Living Muay Thai Student Site
```

The other rails tags, *i.e.* `<%= @student.first_name %>` work as they should.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found it~!

Add `http://` to url.

In a StackOverflow thread (link below) I saw a note that suggested using `http://` to preface the url. I do not use Thunderbird email, but thought I'd try this anyway, and it worked. The link shows correctly in a sent email.

Thread: [Rails mailer and links not working under Thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107627/rails-mailer-and-links-not-working-under-thunderbird)

In my mailer:

```
def new_student_badge_email
    @student = params[:student]
    @badge = params[:badge]
    @admin = params[:admin]
    @url = "http://www.johndcowan.com/living_muay_thai"
    
    mail(to: @student.email, subject: 'LMT You Earned a New Badge')   
  end
```

Odd how something so simple would change how a link is displayed in an email.